# How could you create the initial state node of a graph domain in Burlap?

Tags: java, reinforcement-learning

https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud600/lessons/3780788560/concepts/40374085350923

At the above link it refers that in order to create the initial state of a graph domain you execute this command:
GraphDefinedDomain.getState(domain, 0)

But **getState** does **not exist** as a static method at the current Burlap library.

So how could you create the initial state node of a graph domain in Burlap (http://burlap.cs.brown.edu/)?

(what is the version I am seeing, how much Burlac has changed since then and where could I find a migration guide? could also help)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue. After a bit of research I have found the class [GraphStateNode](http://burlap.cs.brown.edu/doc/burlap/domain/singleagent/graphdefined/GraphStateNode.html), that seem to be working.

See below a sample of how the code looks like:

```
public FirstMDP(double p1, double p2, double p3, double p4) {
    this.numStates = 6;
    this.dg = new GraphDefinedDomain(numStates);

    // actions for initial state 0
    ((GraphDefinedDomain) this.dg).setTransition(0,0,1,1.); //action a
    ((GraphDefinedDomain) this.dg).setTransition(0,1,2,1.); //action b
    ((GraphDefinedDomain) this.dg).setTransition(0,2,3,1.); //action c

    // actions for all the other states
    ((GraphDefinedDomain) this.dg).setTransition(1,0,1,1.); //action for state 1
    ((GraphDefinedDomain) this.dg).setTransition(2,0,4,1.); //action for state 2
    ((GraphDefinedDomain) this.dg).setTransition(3,0,5,1.); //action for state 3
    ((GraphDefinedDomain) this.dg).setTransition(4,0,2,1.); //action for state 4
    ((GraphDefinedDomain) this.dg).setTransition(5,0,5,1.); //action for state 5    

    this.domain = this.dg.generateDomain();
    this.initState = new GraphStateNode();  // Initial state is created
    ((GraphStateNode) this.initState).setId(0); // Initial state is initialized
    this.rf = new FourParamRF(p1,p2,p3,p4);
    this.tf = new NullTermination();
    this.hashFactory = new SimpleHashableStateFactory();
}
```

Make sure you import GraphStateNode class:

```
import burlap.domain.singleagent.graphdefined.GraphStateNode;
```

Please, let me know if that helps.

Comment: I have reverted back to previous version to be (as more as I can) compatible with the tutorial. Thanks a lot for your answer. It will be useful in the near future